# How to use Library installed using composer in your custom module?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, composer, authorize.net

I have installed the Authorize.net library in Magento using composer. Now, this library is available in the vendor directory but I don't have any idea how to use it in my custom module.
The directory structure of Authorize.net in the vendor directory.
[image: authorize.net structure in vendor directory]

Answer (score 0):

Namespace of that library should be available in the composer.json. I don't have Authorize.net, so below is an example from the Monolog:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"Monolog\\": "src/Monolog"}
},
```

In this case you can use Logger class from src/Logger directory as:
`Monolog\Logger`

Same should work for the Authorize.net